# Swift - UIView scaling

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

#### Question:

What is the appropriate to size a subview (or set of subviews) so that they fit (scale) to the appropriate bounds - or in this case make sure the blue circle fits inside the yellow square.  Picture and playground code below!

[image]

```
import UIKit


let topLevelFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)

let topView = UIView(frame: topLevelFrame)
topView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
topView


let windowFrame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 300, 300)
let windowView = UIView(frame: windowFrame)
windowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
topView.addSubview(windowView)

topView

let contentFrame = CGRectMake(-200, -200, 400, 400)
let contentView = UIView(frame: contentFrame)
//contentView.alpha = 5
contentView.layer.cornerRadius=200
contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

contentView


windowView.clipsToBounds = true
windowView.addSubview(contentView)

windowView.bounds
windowView.frame


// How do I fit the blue circle to scale appropriately inside the yellow square?

topView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code to the following:

```
let contentFrame = CGRectMake(windowFrame.origin.x, windowFrame.origin.y, windowFrame.size.width, windowFrame.size.height)
let contentView = UIView(frame: contentFrame)

contentView.layer.cornerRadius = windowFrame.size.height / 2.0
contentView.center = CGPoint(x:windowFrame.size.width / 2.0, y:windowFrame.size.height / 2.0)

contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

contentView
```